# Angular Material Elevate Doesn't show between 2 components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 components in Angular with material design, header and body, where the header is a toolbar using the 'mat-elevation-z4' class:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z4">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  class='search-bar'>
    <mat-label>Search something...</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="white" class='but-margin'> 
    <mat-icon>face </mat-icon>
     Account 
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and a sample body:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

However, after I insert the components in root component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>
```

they appear close to each other but the header is not on top of the body and the shadow does not appear. Is there any way to solve this without adding some space between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, just add `style="z-index:2"` to `<mat-toolbar>`

> When elements overlap, the **z-index** determines the order of the
>   different layers that the elements will form. Generally, one element
>   will cover another element if its **z-index** value is greater than that
>   of the second element.

**Exemple "z-index":**

```css
.boite-tirets { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: dashed;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.boite-doree { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3; /* .boite-doree sera au-dessus de .boite-verte et .boite-tirets */
  background: gold;
  width: 80%;
  left: 60px;
  top: 3em;
}
.boite-verte { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2; /* .boite-verte sera au-dessus de .boite-tirets */
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  left: 65%;
  top: -25px;
  height: 7em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="boite-tirets">White box
  <span class="boite-doree">Gold box</span>
  <span class="boite-verte">Green box</span>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z4" style="z-index:2">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  class='search-bar'>
    <mat-label>Search something...</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="white" class='but-margin'> 
    <mat-icon>face </mat-icon>
     Account 
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Here is an example StackBlitz: [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-toolbar-with-sidenav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html)

**DEMO:**

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work... I see in your root component you only have the navbar component and use routing to the other pages. I think I should just do the same and get rid of this problem

Comment: Please consider explaining what the `z-index` CSS attribute does so that others can understand what exactly you're doing.

Comment: tried with routing and z-index but the body is still on top. Cannot figure out what am I missing

Comment: Solved it by adding "position: fixed" to styles

Comment: you could use position:relative as well if you don't want the content overlapping